# Three choices in shortcut options

Tags: nsis

we have our installer where are some choices to create shortcuts
1) create shortcut for current user
2) create shortcut for all users
3) do not create any shortcut

The first option is checked as default, if I check any other it work well..the problem is that if I check for example 3rd option, move to next page and come back there are 2 choices checked - 1st (default) and 3rd (selected).

I am very new to NSIS and can't find better way than I did it as the code is not very friendly for me.
I would appreciate advice.

Thanks,

This is what I have in my installation options .ini :

```
[Field 5]
Type=GroupBox
Left=1
Right=-1
Top=80
Bottom=144
Text="Choice of shortcuts:"
State=""

[Field 6]
Type=RadioButton
Left=10
Right=-10
Top=96
Bottom=108
Text="Create shortcuts for all users"
State=1
Flags=GROUP|NOTIFY

[Field 7]
Type=RadioButton
Left=10
Right=-10
Top=112
Bottom=124
Text="Create shortcuts only for a current user"
State=0
Flags=NOTIFY

[Field 8]
Type=RadioButton
Text="Do not create shortcut"
Flags=NOTIFY
State=0
Left=10
Right=-10
Top=128
Bottom=140
```

Then later in nsis script:

```
IntCmp $ShortcutsForAllUsers 1 ShortcutsForAll ShortcutsForCurrentUser ShortcutsForCurrentUser

ShortcutsForAll:
 SetShellVarContext all  
 goto done

ShortcutsForCurrentUser:
 SetShellVarContext current 
 goto done

NoShortcuts:
 goto done

done:
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Maybe you could try nsDialogs. This InstallOption plug-in you use is very old and now it is deprecated which may cause this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The InstallOptions page should remember its state as long as you don't extract it every time in the page create callback function.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include InstallOptions.nsh
ChangeUI All "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UIs\modern.exe"

Function .onInit
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_EXTRACT_AS "...\test.ini" "iosp.ini"
FunctionEnd

Var ShortcutMode

Page Custom MyShortcutPageCreate MyShortcutPageLeave
Page Components
Page InstFiles 

Function MyShortcutPageCreate
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "iosp.ini"
FunctionEnd

Function MyShortcutPageLeave
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $0 "iosp.ini" "Settings" "State"
${If} $0 > 0
    IntOp $ShortcutMode $0 - 6 ; Map .ini Field Id to 0 (or empty), 1 or 2
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
${If} $ShortcutMode = 0
    SetShellVarContext all  
${ElseIf} $ShortcutMode = 1
    SetShellVarContext current 
${EndIf}
...
SectionEnd
```

There is a problem with this design, `SetShellVarContext current` might not map $SMPrograms to the correct startmenu folder because UAC can elevate a process with a different Administrator user...